# inheritance between buttons C# - windows form

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a doubt simple principle in C # windows form. 
I have two forms: FormA and FormB. 
The formA has buttonA button with one messagebox => `MessageBox.Show ("FormA");`

The FormB is inherited from FormA whose buttonA changed so I can write another messagebox => `Console.WriteLine ("FormB");`

Until then all right, but I need the event of FormB button to run before the button FormA the event, ie: First `MessageBox.Show ("FormB")` then `MessageBox.Show ("FormA");`

How do I do that?

Comment: There is only one (of those) buttons per form instance. You have probably added an event twice (in say the OnLoad [?] method of both form classes). Don't do that. (Actually, consider *not* using inheritance at all here.)

Comment: Get the event handler to call a virtual method. Then in the overridden method do the new work before calling the base method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call event handler of base class from overridden event handler in derived class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class FormA : Form
    {
        private readonly Button buttonA;

        public virtual void ButtonAClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FormA");
        }

        public FormA()
        {
            this.buttonA = new Button()
            {
                Text = "buttonA",
                Top = 10,
                Left = 10
            };
            this.buttonA.Click += ButtonAClick;
            this.Controls.Add(buttonA);
        }
    }

    public class FormB : FormA
    {
        public override void ButtonAClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FormB");
            base.ButtonAClick(sender, e);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new FormB());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the base method by using the `base` keyword.

Lets assume you have a FormB inheriting from FormA and you have overridden the Button1Click method:

```
public override void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // execute the base class code first
   base.Button1Click(sender, e);

   // call your code specific for B
}
```

However, using inheritance for this seems strange, maybe if you describe your problem, we can find a better solution than this.